# xcode doesn't recognize my device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning

I've connected a new device for testing. These are the steps I performed:

1. in the provision of apple development center I added the device
2. connected the device
3. in xcode open organizer -->the device is shown
4. click on Click the "Use for Development" button
5. click on provisioning add added manualy the provision from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`
6. now when I click on the device I see it has provisioning of `iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *`
7. added to member center - selected an account  Apple Id that has a team provisioning as well as development
8. return to my project and try to choose it as a device, but I can't see it

What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure your device supports the development version of the sdk.

Comment: @Desdenova how can i check that?

Comment: From Xcode, if your deployment target is 7.0 make sure your device is using iOS 7

Comment: @Desdenova my target is 6.1 and the device is using ios 5, if I change the targert to lower and I'm using ARC do i have to change that as well?

Comment: iOS 5.0 is good for ARC if that's what you meant.

Comment: @Desdenova yep that was one of my questions, how do i set it to 5 in xcode 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, change it like this.

[image]